# "RPC Server is unavailable" on Windows 7 Client with Samba3 making logon impossible

Tags: windows-7, samba, domain-controller, rpc, login

I am running an Samba 3.4.* Server with LDAP Backend on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS as a PDC for purely Windows 7 Clients (about 50). It worked quite fine for a long time, but now sometimes on some machines (really strange to replicate) I cannot login, because he tells me that there are no logon servers. When I look in the machines eventlog after logging in locally, the only error it shows is: "RPC Server is unavailable". The system was ported quite a while back from another machine running the same software versions to this new one. Are there maybe trust or caching issues between the workstations and the domain controller? The number of machines affecting is steadily increasing and so do you know any reason as to why this problem occurs?

Any information on workstation and domain trust would also be welcome (After googleing I did not find anything really enlightening).

Comment: Have a look at the [nltest](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158148) utility - you can do things like `nltest /dsgetdc:<domain>` to find your logon server etc.

Comment: That tool was great help, thank you for that, after about a day tinkering, I hope I now have rooted out the problem, but who knows. I would accept you helpful advice, but with a comment that's kinda hard ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Reposted comment)

Have a look at the nltest utility - you can do things like nltest /dsgetdc: to find your logon server etc.